# Multiple lightbox galleries on single page

Tags: lightbox

I'm trying to have 6 different thumbnails and each one to have its own lightbox gallery. I'm having trouble linking the other images in the gallery to each thumbnail. WHere do I begin? I am using a site that has already been set up. I'm just trying to add in the six separate galleries because right now all thumbnails are in one gallery.
Here is the base code I'm starting with:

```
<a href="images2/Topo_collection/sunrise/SunriseSet-1.jpg"
   rel="lightbox[sunrise]" title="Sunrise Set ">
     <img src="images2/Topo_collection/sunrise/SunriseSet-thumb2.jpg"
      alt="Modern artisan handmade ceramic decorative relief tile Topo Collection Sunrise Set lead-free glaze"border="0"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [here](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

You can use rel attribute to distinguish galleries. as like bellow :-

In first image you can use

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery1]" title="my caption">image #1</a>
```

and in second image

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery2]" title="my caption">image #2</a>
```